# Why margin 0 can't delete blank space to css?

Tags: html, css

The img.jpg can be downloaded and save in the same directory with the following css file.

[image]

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#header {
    width: 917px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:2px solid red;
}   
#logo h1 {
    margin: 0 ;
    float: left;
    padding: 50px 0 0 40px;
    font-size: 36px; 
    border:2px solid red;
}
#logo h2 {
    margin: 0 ;
    float: left;
    padding: 72px 0 0 60px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border:2px solid red;
}
#menu {
    margin: 0 ;
    float: right;
    border:2px solid red;
    padding: 70px  0 0 0 ;
}
#menu li {
    display: inline;
}
#splash {
    width: 877px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
            <h1>company web</h1>
            <h2><a href="#">new life new start</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" accesskey="1" title="">contact us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" accesskey="2" title="">about us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" accesskey="3" title="">project</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" accesskey="4" title="">product</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" accesskey="5" title="">service</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="splash">
    <a href="#"><img src="img.jpg" /></a>
</div>
</body>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

To save the css file as test.html and open it with firefox.

[image]

Why can't get the result as the following ?

[image]

For the #menu , `margin: 0 ;padding: 70px  0 0 0 ;` it don't work at all ,why?

Comment: can you add code in jsfiddle?

Comment: You can always inspect element and see where that gap comes from.

Comment: i check to this it's same result what is problum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know mostly html element has their some default property. Its because of that you should use [css reset](http://cssreset.com/) in your css file to manage that all.

In your case if you use

```
#menu  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Then you get expected.

or you can use universal class using `*`

```
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this to your style

```
#menu ul {
    padding: 0px;
}
```